# Raising the exception, ignoring the code and transfering the control to while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is my code in which my while loop is calling my function (function_called) to process the log file. When there is an exception when my function is processing each line then it should ignore rest of the code and transfer the control back to while loop to go to the next line.

So it should be:

--Fetch Line--
--If index error exception in line--
--ignore code--
--move to the next line

My code overview is mentioned below

```
def function_called():
                try:
                     --Something is happening here--
                except IndexError:
                --If there is an exception then code needs to be ignored
                and it should be transfered to the while loop to go to the next line--



f = open('/data/qantasflight/run/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2016-03-31.txt', 'r')
while True:
        line = ''
        while len(line) == 0 or line[-1] != '\n':
                tail = f.readline()
                if tail == '':
                        continue
                line = tail

        print (line, end='')
#               print (line)
        sleep(0.1)
        function_called(line)
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `pass` keyword?

Comment: I tried pass, does not suit my requirement, ideally if there is an exception then the further code needs to be ignored and control should be given back to while loop.

Comment: `pass`, in your example, will ignore the error and go to the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the exception at the place where you want to handle it, i.e. in the `while` loop.

```
def function_called():
    """ something, which might raise an index error """

while True:
    """ do stuff """
    try:
        function_called(line)
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

If you want to do more explicit error handling in `function_called`, you can do that and just `raise` the exception again:

```
def function_called():
    try:
        """ something, which might raise an index error """
    except IndexError:
        """ more error handling """
        raise
```

Check out the [chapter about error handling in the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: I want to handle the exception in my function but don't want to use "raise", instead i want to know a way on how to ignore the entire code and pass the control to while loop to process the next line. This is what i wanted - --Fetch Line-- --If index error exception in line-- --ignore code-- --move to the next line

Comment: Ah, then check out the first comment to your original by @loutre, just `pass` inside the function when you encounter an error. This of course only works if `function_called(line)` is the last statement in the `while` loop, and therefore I'd prefer more explicit error handling. Otherwise you need to either `raise`, or return a meaningful value for checking, to prematurely continue the loop.